# How to replace search method with sql query in odoo

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-13

When I have too many product and I used the following filter, the loading time is long.So I want to replace with query.How can I change my search into query?I know the basic query but cant convert my search into query because I don't know how to use for with_context in query.

```html
class valuation_report(models.Model):
      _inherit = "stock.valuation.layer"
      def _get_current_user(self):
          for r in self:
              r.user_id = self.env.user
      def _search_branch(self, operator, value):
          warehouse_id= self.env['stock.warehouse'].search([('branch_id','=',self.env.user.branch_id.id)])
          product_ids = self.env['product.product'].with_context(warehouse=warehouse_id.ids).search([]).filtered(lambda p:p.qty_available > 0)
          return [('product_id','in',product_ids.ids)]
      user = fields.Many2one('res.users', compute=_get_current_user, search=_search_branch)
```

Comment: Please post table description (DDL), sample data (as text - **no images**) and the expected output of that data. Also include a textual description of the issue for those of us fluent in SQL but do not speak your obfuscation language (odoo(.

Comment: If you have a _lot_ of products then raw SQL will not necessarily help - you may need to create indexes to help Postgres find the query results quickly.  So a first step should be to find out what SQL Odoo is issuing when it queries the database, and then run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <sql>` in pgsql to find out why the queries are slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. Put `log_level = debug_sql` in your Odoo configuration file. This way you will see what SQL in the logs and this will guide you to understand what `with_context` is doing.
2. If you really need to transform everything into SQL, use `self.env.cr.execute("SELECT ... FROM ...")` and then `rows = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()`